# Add function in a trie structure does not work properly

Tags: c, struct, trie

I'm trying to write a function to add words in a trie, and count the number of times it has been added. But it always returns 1.
Can anybody help me?

```
    struct node
{
    struct node* next;
    struct node* child;
    char data;
    int value;
};
typedef struct node Node;
Node* getNode(char data)
{
    Node* newptr;
    newptr = calloc(1,sizeof(Node));
    newptr->next = NULL;
    newptr -> child = NULL;
    newptr->data = data;
    newptr -> value = 0;
    return newptr;
}

Node* add(Node* parent,char* str)
{
    Node* current;
    current = parent->child;
    while (current != NULL && current->data != str[0])
    {
        current = current->next;
    }
    if (current == NULL)
    {
        current = getNode(str[0]);
        if (str[0] == 0)
        {
            current->value = 1;
            return current;
        }
        return add(current,str + 1);
    }
    if (str[0] == 0)
    {
        (current->value)++;
        return current;
    }
    return add(current,str+1);
}
```

cm: getNode() and Node definitions added!

Comment: Please include the definition of `Node` in the question.

Comment: `current = getNode(str[0]);` I doubt this. Probably does not work as expected.

Comment: Also provide getNode function and where you call add function

Comment: I've implemented tries a few times in my life, but I do not understand what you want to do there. For example, the `while` loop in the 4th row, how is it good for?

Comment: @Codor updates added!